# Laptop slows down while charging battery

Tags: 12.04, mouse, battery

Laptop Model: Dell Lattitude 5440

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.

While charging my laptop battery i've noticed the following:

1. Mouse pointer moves very slowly.
2. computer also slows a bit.

This problem was not observed on windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since [that fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/196275/527764) does not work any more on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-25 on my DELL E5440 laptop, the solution for me is to use a 90W battery charger (instead of the 65W).

I found the idea on [a post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/962712/comments/8) on the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/962712) by Till Seuring.

Answer (score 0):

- Open `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf`.

  ```
  gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
  ```
- Add the following line:

  ```
  options drm_kms_helper poll=N
  ```
- Restart.

As mentioned [here on Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930172#6), if you don't have `local.conf` file you can also try editing `alsa-base.conf`.

It is also a bug and is reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/962712.

Comment: I have done this but could not solve the problem.